# How can I open an URL in Metamask explorer from a mobile navigator website?

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript

How to open the URL of web3 in the Metamask explorer from a href link in that web3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this Metamask git for create deep links:

https://metamask.github.io/metamask-deeplinks/

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-deeplinks

Comment: Is it possible to generate a deep link programmatically?